# Dividing a big dataset into smaller sub-sets in python

Tags: python, time-series, dataset

I have a large time-based data set. it has 120,496 data points. I want to have smaller subsets each with ,say, 600 data points (the problem is with the final series, since the length is not a multiple of 600), I can do this with a lengthy and dirty for loop but I wanted to ask if there are any simple functions that would carry this task out? or if someone could direct towards the right direction as I am a bit lost w this.
I am assuming that this definitely does exist, since from what I know, some audio file analysis methodologies sort of divide the voice sample into smaller pieces.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be nice to see whatever you have done just to see which direction you are heading to

Comment: @linkonabe Hi, I thought since this is the issue stopping me form preforming my analysis, it would save time to specifically address this issue, but thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.array_split(df, n)` splits the dataframe into n sub-dataframes, while `splitDataFrameIntoSmaller(df, chunkSize = n)` splits the dataframe every `chunkSize` rows.

```
# input - df: a Dataframe, chunkSize: the chunk size
# output - a list of DataFrame
# purpose - splits the DataFrame into smaller chunks
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], columns=['TEST'])
df_split = np.array_split(df, 3)
```

You get 3 sub-dataframes:

```
df_split[0] # 1, 2, 3, 4
df_split[1] # 5, 6, 7, 8
df_split[2] # 9, 10, 11
```

With:

```
def splitDataFrameIntoSmaller(df, chunkSize = 10): #10 for default 
    listOfDf = list()
    numberChunks = len(df) // chunkSize + 1
    for i in range(numberChunks):
        listOfDf.append(df[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    return listOfDf

df_split2 = splitDataFrameIntoSmaller(df, chunkSize = 3)
```

You get 4 sub-dataframes:

```
df_split2[0] # 1, 2, 3
df_split2[1] # 4, 5, 6
df_split2[2] # 7, 8, 9
df_split2[3] # 10, 11
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, however the function 'splitDataFrameIntoSmaller' is not recognised, but I just used the length of indecies based on my chunk size to use the numpy array_splt function. thank you for your input.

Comment: @Ali Kavoosi. Your welcome, Meanwhile I added `splitDataFrameIntoSmaller` function. I forgot it.

Comment: `numberChunks = math.ceil(len(df) / chunkSize)`